# "rails generate dragonfly" returns "Could not find generator dragonfly."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dragonfly-gem

I have a site that was migrated from Heroku to standalone server, and everything is working except images which are hosted on S3.

When pages with images is loaded following error is returned.

```
Started GET "/system/images/W1siZiIsIjIwMTYvMDcvMjIvMTEvMTQvMTUvNzUvSGVhZHNob3RMb2Rub25fRG95bGVDbGF5dG9uX01BWV9BTkQ2NDkzXzFfLmpwZyJdLFsicCIsInRodW1iIiwiMzI2eCJdXQ/picture.jpg" for x.x.x.x at 2016-12-07 04:33:28 +0000

Dragonfly::Configurable::NotConfigured (You need to configure Dragonfly::DataStorage::S3DataStore with bucket_name):
```

I can see that application didn't have dragonfly listed in gemfile,as Heroku seems to do things a little differently, and have reinstalled dragonfly, but when trying to generate a configuration file following error is returned.

```
# rails generate dragonfly
Could not find generator dragonfly.
```

I can see that dragonfly 0.9.15 has been installed.

I have tried manually creating *config/initializers/dragonfly.rb* with following content, but still get the same error when trying to load images.

```
require 'dragonfly'

app = Dragonfly[:app]
app.configure_with(:imagemagick)
app.configure_with(:rails)

app.define_macro(ActiveRecord::Base, :image_accessor)
app.datastore = Dragonfly::DataStorage::S3DataStore.new({
  :bucket_name        => 'S3_BUCKET',
  :access_key_id      => 'S3_KEY',
  :secret_access_key  => 'S3_SECRET',
  :region             => 'S3_REGION'
})
```

Did anyone had a similar issue.

I am not sure why is "Could not find generator dragonfly" returned.